# ValueError: Unknown scheme for proxy URL URL('socks://127.0.0.1:7890/')

Tags: proxy, openai-api, chatgpt-api

OS:ubuntu20.04

from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI(api_key=api_key)

raise ValueError(f"Unknown scheme for proxy URL {url!r}")
ValueError: Unknown scheme for proxy URL URL('socks://127.0.0.1:7890/')

I encountered this problem，when i used gpt.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this format, although we are unsure what your trying to do here, this is my best guest. https://socks.127.0.0.1:7890/

Comment: I changed the proxy url in os.environ and the program ran.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. How to change the proxy url in os.environ?